# How to get the bounds of a projection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm building a small function to create a grid based on a size and a projection. This grid will be worldwide or more specifically covering the whole projection area of use.

Is there a way to get the bounds of a projection in the CRS coordinate system in GEE ?

I try to mimic the behavior of the Python `pyproj` lib:

```py
from pyproj import CRS

crs_3857 = CRS.from_epsg(3857)
crs_min_x, crs_min_y, crs_max_x, crs_max_y = crs_3857.area_of_use.bounds
```

In GEE I'm stuck after defining the projection:

```py
import ee 

ee.Initialize() 

proj = ee.Projection("EPSG:3857")
crs_min_x, crs_min_y, crs_max_x, crs_max_y = proj. ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's nothing built in for that.  It would make a good feature request though.

Comment: done in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/313937471